# How do I convert my existing Telegram group to a local group?

Tags: instant-messaging, telegram-messenger

Telegram has added a [new option](https://telegram.org/blog/contacts-local-groups) to pin a group to a location, but I only see the option to create a new group. 
I would like to pin my existing supergroup to a location, how to do that?

Comment: it's not the way it works and it's not pin it's to add, the option works as GPS based group upon your location, if you created a simple group before it is not a location based group.

Comment: so there's no way to "upgrade"? what is the fundamental difference (except geo tag which is I believe 2 decimals of latitude and longitude)

Comment: geo chats are only serve as a close to you users or friends that are not far from you it is more kind of a local communication chats.

Comment: yes I know. We have our condominium chat for example, which I would like to convert to a local group

Comment: This was my first though to pin local city cycling club chat to city’s location to make it searchable.

Answer (score -1):

It's impossible to convert a regular group to a local one. You could try making a location-based group and sending a link to it into the regular group but that's about it.